# setTransform () for SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-camera

When recording via TextureView to the screen is not mirrored used setTransform () method:

```
Matrix txform = new Matrix();
mTextureView.getTransform(txform);
txform.setScale((float) newWidth / viewWidth, (float) newHeight / viewHeight);
txform.postTranslate(xoff, yoff);
mTextureView.setTransform(txform);
```

And in my case I use  SurfaceView instead TextureView and it turns out there is this method ...

Question: What should I do in order to mirror does not reflect, and what to use instead setTransform ()?

Answer (score 1):

In order to mirror over Y axis use this:

```
txform.setScale(-(float) newWidth / viewWidth, (float) newHeight / viewHeight, viewWidth / 2.f , 0);
```

Comment: but no method surfaceview setTransform () parameter Matrix?

Comment: @TITAN , surfaceview doesn't provide such API. but you can try to check setScaleX of View : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX%28float%29